# Unit Testing a Basic c# application with repository

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I have a basic .NET application that I am being asked to write a unit test for, but unit tests have always confused me.

This application has two repositories (FoodRepository and DrinkRepository) that return data from a hardcoded list.

Here's the Program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foodSvc = new FoodService();
        var foodId = 12;
        var grade = 98.2d;
        foodSvc.UpdateFoodGrade(foodId, grade);
    }
```

which calls:

```
public void UpdateFoodGrade(int foodId, double grade)
    {
        var foodRepo = new FoodRepository();
        var food = foodRepo.GetFood(foodId);

        food.Grade = grade;

        if (!food.IsPassed)
        {
            var drinkRepository = new DrinkRepository();
            var drink = drinkRepository.GetDrink(foodId);

            if (grade >= drink.MinimumPassingGrade)
            {
                food.IsPassed = true;
            }
            else
            {
                food.IsPassed = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is, what unit test(s) typically would someone do here for this? And, can I get some examples?

Been googling and grinding on this, but the concept continues to escape me.

I've historically used full integration tests in test environments, and not really done unit tests.

If anyone needs more of the code to help with this please let me know. I'm super stuck.

Thanks

UPDATE:

I've gotten a lot further thanks to below, but I am still stuck on the rest of the test. Here's what my updated service looks like:

```
public class FoodService
{
    private readonly FoodRepository _foodRepo;
    private readonly DrinkRepository _drinkRepository;

    public FoodService(FoodRepository foodRepo, DrinkRepository drinkRepository)
    {
        _foodRepo = foodRepo;
        _drinkRepository = drinkRepository;
    }

    public void UpdateFoodGrade(int foodId, double grade)
    {
        var food = _foodRepo.GetFood(foodId);

        food.Grade = grade;

        if (!food.IsPassed)
        {
            var drink = _drinkRepository.GetDrink(foodId);

            if (grade >= drink.MinimumPassingGrade)
            {
                food.IsPassed = true;
            }
            else
            {
                food.IsPassed = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Updated Main:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foodRepository = new FoodRepository();
        var drinkRepository = new DrinkRepository();
        var foodSvc = new FoodService(foodRepository, drinkRepository);

        var foodId = 12;
        var grade = 98.2d;

        foodSvc.UpdateFoodGrade(foodId, grade);
    }
}
```

Test So far (I have no idea what to do next)

```
[TestMethod]
    public void UpdateFoodGrade_Test()
    {
        //Arrange
        var foodId = 12;
        var grade = 98.2d;           
        var expected = true;

        var food = new Food() { FoodId = foodId };
        var drink = new Drink() { DrinkId = foodId };

        var foodRepositoryMock = new Mock<FoodRepository>();
        foodRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.GetFood(foodId)).Returns(food).Verifiable();

        var drinkRepositoryMock = new Mock<DrinkRepository>();
        drinkRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.GetDrink(foodId)).Returns(drink).Verifiable();

        var foodService = new FoodService(foodRepositoryMock.Object, drinkRepositoryMock.Object);

        //Act
        var actual = foodService.UpdateFoodGrade(foodId, grade);

        //Assert
        foodRepositoryMock.Verify();
        drinkRepositoryMock.Verify();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

I went ahead and refactored in the interfaces, etc. Here's how it shook out:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void UpdateLessonGrade_IsPassingGrade()
    {
        //Arrange
        var lessonId = 12;

        var lesson = new Lesson() { LessonId = lessonId };
        var module = new Module() { ModuleId = lessonId };

        var lessonRepositoryMock = new Mock<ILessonRepository>();
        lessonRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetLesson(lessonId)).Returns(lesson);

        var moduleRepositoryMock = new Mock<IModuleRepository>();
        moduleRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetModule(lessonId)).Returns(module);

        var lessonService = new LessonService(lessonRepositoryMock.Object, moduleRepositoryMock.Object);

        //Act
        lessonService.UpdateLessonGrade(12, 98.2d);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(lesson.IsPassed); // assuming it should pass in this condition
        Assert.AreEqual(98.2d, lesson.Grade); // expected Lesson Grade should be what you expected the grade to be after you call UpdateLessonGrade
    }
```

Comment: This code has a lot of tight coupling to implementation concerns that would make it difficult to unit test in isolation without knock on effects.

Comment: Before this code can be unit tested successfully it would first need to be refactored to be more unit test friendly.

Comment: You will need to study "dependecy injection" - that way you can make it more test-friendly

Comment: I suggest you watch [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412) for an explanation of how you can write testable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on a mobile device right now, I can try to update the answer later this weekend, but this should get you started.

Refactor your method to use instance variables instead of direct instantiation in the method. Add them as parameters to your constructor. In the main method create your repository instances and pass them to the service constructor.

Now you can use something like Moq or the in memory provider for entity framework.

As for what to test, basically test every piece of branching logic. At a minimum, each piece of an if statement and the else conditions. You should also test what happens when your repository objects don't find what you're looking for (e.g. returns null). Offhand, I'm counting at least six tests.

**Update:** *Bravo! Looking at your updated code in the question, everything is on the right track.*

In your test method, you'll want to add:

```
var foodService = new FoodService(foodRepositoryMock.Object, drinkRepositoryMock.Object);
```

That will initialize your service with the mock objects.

Then you'll want to call your service with test parameters like:

```
foodService.UpdateFoodGrade(12, 98.2d);
```

The last part is check your food object using asserts like:

```
Assert.IsTrue(food.IsPassed) // assuming it should pass in this condition
Assert.Equals(98.2d, food.Grade); // expectedFoodGrade should be what you expected the grade to be after you call UpdateFoodGrade
```

It looks like you'll also need to flesh out the instance of your Drink object a little bit more.  You need to specify a value for `MinimumPassingGrade` since it's used to drive the decision logic in your if statement, for example, if you want the `food.IsPassed = true` to trigger, you would instantiate the drink object like so:

```
var drink = new Drink() { DrinkId = foodId, MinimumPassingGrade = 50.0d };
```

You would create test methods for each of the other various test cases, failed the minimum, when it's equal to the score, if you can't find the food in the food repo, or the drink in the drink repo, etc.

One other note, you only need to worry about `Verifiable` mocks when you need to know that a method was/wasn't called. For these tests, I probably wouldn't verify that methods were called (creates tighter coupling between your test and the implementation vs. the behavior). You'd want to verify that the methods were called only if something in your service code truly depends on knowing that it was called.  e.g. if you're using Entity Framework and you wanted to make sure you didn't forget to call `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: thanks. This is a good lead, but some example code would be super helpful too. I’ll press on in the meantime with these ideas. Thank you for any further info.

Comment: Jason Armstrong: Updated code above, can you still help?

Comment: No problem. Glad it was helpful!

Comment: Ack, getting this on the test run: Message: Test method WriteUnitTest.UnitTests.Services.FoodServiceUnitTests.UpdateFoodGrade_IsPassingGrade threw exception: 
System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: m => m.GetFood(<>c__DisplayClass0_0.lessonId)

Comment: That sounds like FoodRepository or DrinkRepository is a sealed class or not an interface, in which case, Moq won't work. I'm not sure if other mocking libraries would work.

Comment: So if I create an interface, and use IFoodRepository, and IDrinkRepository, that should fix it?

Comment: Yep, it should.

Comment: this is causing a chain reaction of refactoring since now FoodService doesn't have a constructor that takes interfaces vs Repositories, etc. Do you think it's necessary to have to make changes this far up the chain to make this work right?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, such code can't be "normally" unit-tested without preliminary refactoring. But you still have one (bit dirty) option: Shims mechanism of MS Fakes Library.

It allows you to substitute any method or property of any type (including static, non-public and system) with any arbitrary code. In your case you may create a `ShimsContext` in you test method, and give some fake behavior for `FoodRepository.GetFood()` and `DrinkRepository.GetDrink()` methods, for example, empty body doing nothing. So, when your test runs, your stub code gonna be executed instead of the actual code of repository classes. So you will test only Service code without executing code of repositories.

You may check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2017) for quick introduction to the library.

And please keep in mind that Shims is not a way of good unit-testing, It is just a tool to deal with such non-testable code in case when you absolutely need to unit-test it somehow without changing the code itself.